# Match only final character of regex

Tags: python, regex

I have some Python code that involves a lot of re.sub() commands. In some cases, I want to replace a character but only if it comes after certain other characters. The following is an example of how I currently am doing this in python:

```
secStress = "[aeiou],"[-1]
```

So my input for this would be a string like "a,s I walk, I hum." And I want to replace that first comma but not the "a" that comes before it.

The problem is that Python doesn't like when I give it a variable as input for re.sub(). Is there a way I can write a regex that specifies that only its final character is supposed to be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for either a capturing group/backreference or a positive lookbehind solution:

```
s = "a,s I walk, I hum."

# Capturing group / backreference
print(re.sub(r"([aeiou]),", r"\1", s))

# Positive lookbehind
print(re.sub(r"(?<=[aeiou]),", "", s))
```

See the  [Python demo](http://ideone.com/Pmt4XM).

**First approach details**

The `([aeiou])` is a capturing group that matches a vowel and stores it in a special memory buffer that you can refer to from the replacement pattern using backreferences. Here, the Group ID is 1, so you can access that value using `r"\1"`.

**Second approach details**

The `(?<=[aeiou])` is a positive lookbehind that only checks (but  does not add the text to the match value) if there is a vowel immediately before the current position. So, only those commas are matched that are preceded with a vowel and it is enough to replace with an empty string to get rid of the comma since it is the only symbol kept in the match.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,

```
>>> import re
>>> def doit(matchobj):
...     return matchobj.group()[0]
... 
>>> re.sub(r'[aeiou],', doit, "a,s I walk, I hum.")
'as I walk, I hum.'
```

If the regex matches then `doit` is called with the object that matched. Whatever string `doit` returns (and it must be a string) is put in place of the match.